# Jq index() Not Found

Tags: python, jq

Executing the following jq command works fine on Mac OS Catalina (jq version 1.6) :

```
echo $(jq '.paths | to_entries | map(select(.value[].tags | index("Tag123"))) | from_entries' custom.json)
```

However executing it on CentOS (CentOS release 6.9 (Final)) (jq version 1.3) returns the following error :

```
echo $(jq '.paths | to_entries | map(select(.value[].tags | index("Shell"))) | from_entries' custom.json)
error: index is not defined
.paths | to_entries | map(select(.value[].tags | index("Shell"))) | from_entries
                                                 ^^^^^
1 compile error
```

Comment: Not sure why you are doing `pip install jq` does not install the jq binary, but a python package to be used non-interactively. Post your `jq --version` from the command line on both the versions

Comment: @Inian Sorry, you are correct; just realized your point; updated with jq versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `pip install jq` does not install the executable that you can use interactively from the command line, but as a python package, which you can use only in scripts.

As for the disparity in the usage of `index()` function, you seem to be using an older/outdated version of `jq-1.3` in CentOS which does not have the `index()`, `rindex()` functions.

From the [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/NEWS)

> New features in 1.4 since 1.3:
>
> - string built-ins:
> - **index, rindex, indices**

Your version on MacOS `jq-1.6` has those functions available.

Comment: Ended up manually installing jq from : https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64
as I couldn't get it to work via yum, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Evidently the version of jq installed via pip was version 1.3 (which is ancient history) or earlier. `index/1` was only introduced as a built-in filter after the release of jq 1.3.

If you are absolutely stuck with jq 1.3, you could use `contains/1` if you don't need the integer index.